# Xamarin Forms Carousel view is throwing index out of range error on subsequent loads

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `<CarouselView />` wrapped in a `<RefreshView />`:

```
<RefreshView x:DataType="local:CarouselViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <CarouselView x:Name="MyCarousel"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource carouselDataTemplateSelector}">
  </CarouselView>
</RefreshView>
```

When it first loads, no problem. If I navigate away and then back to this view, I get:

```
[RecyclerView] Cannot scroll to position a LayoutManager set. Call setLayoutManager with a non-null argument.
**System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:** 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'
```

The view model is quite simple, and I would expect the "IsRefreshing" prop to resolve any indexing issues. It seems apparent that modifying the collection (i.e. web request to see if anything is new) is causing the error? Here's the view model:

```
public class CarouselViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        public Services.ICarouselService DataStore => DependencyService.Get<Services.ICarouselService>();
        
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; }

        public CarouselViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());        
        }

        
        async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Items.Clear();
                var items = await DataStore.ListAsync(true);

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
        }
        
    }
```

I've included the error right before it is thrown related to the recycler view as this may have something to do with it. It seems that the carousel is not actually refreshing. Should the isBusy flag be preventing this?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug/limitation in how RefreshView and Carousel interact. Android's RecyclerView may be trying to use an index, but the internal list (that Items is source to) isn't in the expected state. Change `ExecuteLoadItemsCommand` to NOT work with `Items` directly. No `Items.Clear()` or `Items.Add()`. Instead, work with a local variable, i'll call it "newItems", build a new list, when the list is done, do `Items = newItems;` Or you may be able to simply do `Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(items);`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve interesting idea. Only issue I'm facing now is nothing is showing in the carousel, but error stopped.

Comment: Does it only show nothing when you navigate back to the page?  Its okay first appearance?  Hack idea: do something that forces a refresh, after the page appears. First, as a test, have a button you can press. In button click logic, ... actually I'm not sure best way to force refresh. Google for that. Or as an extreme test, build a new ObservableCollection, and set Items to that. Then set index or item to [0] again. My thinking is to find something that will get the page working again. Once have that, a hack solution is to have OnAppearing cause that after a delay ...

Comment: ... which is a bit tricky, because you want to let `OnAppearing` return, so that page gets displayed. Maybe (last statement in OnAppearing): `Task.Run( () => { Task.Delay(250); Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread ( () => HackMethodToRefreshCarousel(); } }`. This starts a background task, which delays 250 milliseconds, then returns to UI thread to do "something" that refreshes carousel.